# how to convert list in to comma separated in c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

i have one list. in this list multiple type for example. course like mca,bca and mca store the c,c# text and bca store the java,.net. so i want to result mca : c,c#. here i have write this query but i get the error like this 
"Expression cannot contain lambda expressions".
below i have write this code in c#.

```
foreach (var i in clist)
{
    string.Join(",", i.listcouse.Where(x => x.type == "mca"))
}
```

here i am trying this query but i don't return result so please let me know what's the problem in my query.

Comment: You have to assign the result to a variable

Comment: also try this way but still getting error.

Comment: Can  you share how your course class look like?

Comment: The show what you tried (and you would be better of using a `SelectMany` query

Comment: @StephenMuecke you mean replace where to SelectMany?

Comment: No, to avoid the `foreach` loop

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you please write the query in this comment?

Comment: You need to show you models (and indicate which property your trying to join)

Comment: @StephenMuecke [DataMember]
        public string type
        {
            get { return m_type; }
            set { m_type = value; }
        } this get set are used

Comment: Edit your question! And all the models - what is `clist` and what is `listcouse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replicate scenario by considering you need to select coursename where coursetype is like "mca".

Query will look like as below

```
 var result = string.Join(",", c.listCourse.Where(lc => lc.Type == "MCA").Select(lc=>lc.CourseName));
```